# nodejs keystone : stop html entity replacing "<" with "&lt;"

Tags: node.js, pug, keystonejs

Want to render page sections with html coming from the data base. Using keystone with default jade & mongo.

To test in my init (view.on('init', function(next) {) function i have

```
 locals.intro = "my intro<b>bolder 2</b>";
```

On my jade template source this gets rendered with the opening and closing angular brackets escaped  :

```
  my intro&lt;b&gt;bolder 2&lt;/b&gt;
```

How do I stop this? Similarly for fields from the data base console.log shows the expected value, as expected like  :

```
  </b>
```

but on the page its escaped.

NOTE : do not think its related to decodeURIComponent as don't want to decode on server, but want server to stop encoding before sending to browser, part of page render.

Comment: you need decodeURIComponent

Comment: FYI this is not coming from the client but is going to client. Its in db - in correct way. if i sent from node.js to a page it looks fine but from a keystone view get this issue. What does that mean? Need to add it where and how ? So its there for all views? @SetupX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can request Jade not to escape characters by using !

```
// if intro = "<b> bolder </b>"

!= intro // will render as <b> bolder </b>
```

However, be careful if the source of any of the unescaped content is untrusted (i.e. users) as this can lead to very bad things.

Comment: Right need to sanatisize when users enter the text - i agree. Is there a helper for that? To make sure its only acceptable html?

Comment: Well that is what Jade does for you by escaping the characters in the first place!  You can write a helper to sanitize your user input (just search on SO) but to be quite honest my approach is just to use the built-in functionality of Jade and never route user generated input for in escaped display

Comment: well we are using a WYSIWYG editor to let  users compose html.  i will search for a good cleaner.

Comment: One approach is to whitelist a bunch of tags that are available to users (and are harmless) then strip out everything else.  This way users are happy (their text comes out pretty) and you are happy (random people are not executing scripts on your site)